# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 18

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to run odoo on machine without internet connection. I've just installed odoo using internet connection, so it works, while there is internet connection. But when I turn internet off I have this error after logging:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 18
    at fetch.then.res (http://10.10.10.15:8069/web:21:142)
    at <anonymous>
```

Password and email are correct, and they are in db. There are no errors in log file.

**UPDATE**

This error can be tracked in browser. And comes from web.assets_backend.js.

Comment: The server might be returning an HTML error page.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing odoo from localhost if you have it locally in your machine

```
http://localhost:8069
```